# Does this code use the Proxy or Singleton pattern, or both of them?

Tags: java, design-patterns

```
public interface SomeObject {
    void process();
}

public class SomeObjectImpl implements SomeObject {

    public SomeObjectImpl() {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void process() {
        ...
    }
}

public class AnotherObject implements SomeObject {
    private SomeObject object;

    @Override
    public void process() {
        if (object == null) {
            object = new SomeObjectImpl();
        }
        object.process();
    }
}
```

I think it's the Singleton pattern because it states that *a class must ensure that only a single instance should be created and a single object can be used by all other classes*. In the example, when `SomeObject` is `null` an instance is created as required.

However, it also looks like the Proxy pattern is used, because `SomeObject` is the proxy.

Is this code really using both patterns? Or is the Proxy pattern used only?

Comment: Given your question here, and your other (similar) ones, I suggest you have a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as well as **[How do I ask and answer Homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)**. Note, you're expected to ***make your best possible effort to solve your question yourself before asking them here***. Check your karma and answer yourself whether this (and other) questions were truely based on your best efforts?

Comment: @Ivo Mori, Okey, got it and thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ***Singleton Pattern***'s purpose is to ensure that only one instance of the singleton class ever exists.

Does the given code ensure that? *No*, because nothing prevents you from creating as many instances as you like from the two classes `SomeObjectImpl` and `AnotherObject` (by just invoking their default constructor).

***Hint:*** See the [Wikipedia page on Singleton Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) for implementation examples in different languages... and once you've seen how to create singletons – then forget about using them in real code, ever – as it's the best way for creating *untestable software* ⚡ and having *global variable(s)* ⚡ gluing everything together.

---

The ***Proxy Pattern***'s purpose is to control the access to an object or to provide some additional functionality upon accessing an object.

Does the given code look something like that? *Yes*.

The two classes `SomeObjectImpl` and `AnotherObject` implement the interface `SomeObject`. That interface (in terms of the Proxy Pattern) represents the *Subject* providing some action, i.e. the `process` method. The `SomeObjectImpl` class is then the acutal implementation; the *RealSubject* (as named by the Proxy Pattern). While `AnotherObject` class simply *delegates* to the actual implemenation `SomeObjectImpl`, i.e. it's a *Proxy*.

Given that code, the *Proxy*'s purpose (or additional functionality) is to cache an instance of `SomeObjectImpl` for subsequent `process` calls. This makes sense when the object creation is a costly operation. For example, when the `process` method implementation requires the setup of some external resources or requires "big" upfront memory allocations,  ...